# Centering joystick potentiometers in a controller

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, calibration, joystick

I've replaced a joystick in my Dual Shock 4 controller, because it was getting stuck. The readings of the new joystick are offset to right and down.

[image]

I've read that you can recenter the readings by reseting the controller but that didn't work.

I was thinking about soldering another potentiometer in parallel and live adjust it to make the stick read center and then desolder them, measure and replace them with SMD resistors of similar value. Would that work? Should I try something else?

Comment: Use the four corner recal. And if that doesn’t work confirm you got the exact same value and type.

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.*